# How to execute a command after my batch file loads a .jar

Tags: batch-file, server, jar, minecraft

I've got a batch file that starts a `.jar`file but after it finishes loading the `.jar`, it doesn't execute the other commands that run after.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title DWAD
color 0A
cls

:start
echo loading server...
java -Xms3G -Xmx20G -jar DWAD.jar nogui

echo "/say server will restart in 60 seconds"
TIMEOUT /T 30
echo /say server will restart in 30 seconds
TIMEOUT /T 10
echo /say server will restart in 10
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 9
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 8
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 7
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 6
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 5
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 4
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 3
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 2
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say 1
TIMEOUT /T 1
echo /say server restarting
```

How do I instruct the code to run the next command "echo" after the .jar has finished loading?

Thank you!

I've tried using a call command before `java -Xms3G -Xmx20G -jar DWAD.jar nogui` without luck

I've tried using a /wait command after `java -Xms3G -Xmx20G -jar DWAD.jar nogui` without luck too

What I expect is for the batch file to run the next line of code after loading the `.jar` but the result is that it doesn't. The batch file just stops right after it loads the .jar

Comment: type "cmd /?" into command line, that information might help

Comment: (This may actually be something with java, in that case, try starting another batch file that contains the java command)

Comment: Hi! Where would I insert that? at the very beginning?

Comment: Ah wait, just run a .bat with the command cmd /?

Comment: No, open command prompt, windowskey+r type cmd, hit enter, run cmd /?

Comment: Gotcha - was able to do that but not sure what after!

Answer (score 0):

### OP would like to script a Minecraft Server

I have found the plugin I believe I used to do this in the past, it is located here:

https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1263927-win-mac-linux-minecraft-console-client

This should allow him to pass text and commands to the user sin the server while performing functions on the OS too, allowing him to automate the server's shut down as he's looking to do.

Double checked and again looks like the one I used 8 years ago when I had a server for a bit, and as the plugin author says:

> • Single command usage : MinecraftClient.exe username password server
>   "/mycommand"
>
> This will automatically send "/mycommand" to the server, and then the
>   client will automatically leave the server and close.
>
> Useful for use in batch command sending scripts.

This would change your script to be something like this:

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_UN=ServerUserName"
  SET "_PW=ServerPassword"
  SET "_IP=ServerIP"
  title MinecraftClient
  color 0A
  cls
)

CALL :Main

(
  ENDLOCAL
  Exit /B 0
)

:Main
  ECHO.
  ECHO.  Begining Script:


  REM Letting the Users Know about the Count Down
  FOR /L %%L IN (60,-1,1) DO (
    MinecraftClient.exe %_UN% %_PW% %_IP% "/say WARNING: Server will Restart in %%L Seconds!"
    Timeout 1
  )
  ECHO.
  ECHO. Sending Final Notice and Shutting down the Server!
  MinecraftClient.exe  %_UN% %_PW% %_IP%  "/say !!! WARNING: Server GOING DOWN FOR RESTART NOW !!!"

  REM Not sure what the Restart command is offhand.
  MinecraftClient.exe  %_UN% %_PW% %_IP%  "/Restart Command"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Awesome. However, it's not restarting the server :(

The reason I had the /say was because I was trying to get it to say, in-game, that the server is about to reset - to alert anyone connected.

Comment: Is there a way to continue the code even after the .jar is executed? That would help immensely!

Comment: @JimothyBringus  This IS the script running after starting Java as a separate process.  I take it you want to have the stuff that is done after Java starts to be passed to the JAVA server somehow, like you were typing interactively?  In which case, no, that is almost certainly not possible, we would have to know what the software you wee running in Java was and see if it has a way to interact with it remotely

Comment: Yeah, that would be ideal haha.

Ok, so I'm running a minecraft server via this script. When I hide the GUI I'm left with a cmd.exe where I can type in code and have it run inside the server. 

Like if I wrote /say hello everyone, what would return is the server saying "hello everyone" in-game.

I guess there's just not a way to write the batch to make it go "ok, you've ran the jar now continue [here]" where [here] is the additional code that comes after the .jar start line?

Comment: That is an interactive Shell for the server, there are commands to run to send messages from the CLI to the minecraft server, if I recall correctly from the last time I ran one like 8 years ago).  However you can also try a couple of things, and IF the Java app is programmed to allow you to do this then they will work, but essentially you can echo a bunch of lines to the server from a pre-command or from a file, but unless the JAVA app has a timer they will all come at once.  So even if that works I don't think it will accomplish your goal

Comment: @JimothyBringus  I found the Minecraft Server Plugin I used I think, if I found the correct one this should allow you to manage your minecraft server directly from within the CLI by running scripts and echoing text etc  `https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1263927-win-mac-linux-minecraft-console-client`

Comment: @JimothyBringus  I posted the Link to the plugin in the answer as well and could help you script a little automation for your Minecraft server later if you need any help you can message me here on something, sorry I can't PM you I'm not sure if you have enough Rep to chat, but if you do then maybe we can find a time to do that.  I have to head out now though. `• Single command usage : MinecraftClient.exe username password server "/mycommand"

This will automatically send "/mycommand" to the server, and then leave the server and close.

Useful for use in batch command sending scripts.`

Comment: @JimothyBringus I actually realised it was going to be pretty easy to amend the script and tighten it up some so I did that for you, see the answer posted, enter the info needed for your UN PW Server Ip and Edit the command used to shut down the server to be correct as I don't nwo it offhand.

Comment: @JimothyBringus  I'm actually excited to hear back because I miss Minecraft, but I don't have time for it these days, so I feel like by helping you it's almost like I am running a Minecraft server of my own.  Let me live vicariously! :)

Comment: Hi ben! 

Dude thanks so much for the link - I've got the manager connected to my server now.

Quick question - since it uses my login to log into the server, how do I login the server to play? I tried it but then it disconnects the server manager. Any ideas?